# How to pass a run-time string to json::value::string

Tags: c++, json

I am new to JSON, so requesting quick help to apparently simple looking problem but I am stuck. Following piece of code works as the string literal, as I think, is processed at compile time.

```
  json::value postData;
  postData[L"video_file_name"] = json::value::string(L"C:\\\\Processed\\\\ProcessedVideo.avi");
  postData[L"video_file_name"] = json::value::string(U("C:\\\\Processed\\\\ProcessedVideo.avi"));
```

But following code does not even compile where I am trying pass variable string at run-time:

```
 json::value postData;
 std:string  videoString("C:\\\\Processed\\\\ProcessedVideo.avi");
 postData[L"video_file_name"] = json::value::string(videoString.c_str());
```

Above are just code snippet within a larger code module I am trying - requesting for guidance and advice. Thanks.

Comment: Which language is this? This is more likely an issue with how to process JSON in the specific language you are using, than an issue with JSON itself.

Comment: This code snippet shown above is for C++ language.

Comment: Better question is what json library you are using and what the actual compiler error is.